# A quick question about double negative

Tags: meaning

What is the meaning of "Never see no evil"? I found this phrase on a picture of a teddy bear covering his face with his paws, and there are crosses on the ground. I'm guessing it means if you are not watchful, it's deadly dangerous, but
then I think "Never see evil" would do.

Is this proper English?

[image]

Comment: It's grammatical if there's a movie called "No evil" in which case the Teddy bear's advising us  to "Never see ‘No evil‘." With the proper punctuation the sentence makes more sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are the three wise monkeys who, respectively, "see no evil, hear no evil, speak no evil".

This is a play on that phrase, somewhat like the bear is saying "I ain't never gonna see no evil!", and covers his eyes.

It's a weak joke at best.

Answer (score -1):

Never see no evil practically means "always see evil". Negating negative would always result in positive. The best way to explain this would be the rules of mathematics; "when a negative number is multiplied to another negative number, the result is positive."

Comment: I hope you could accept my answer if I was able to help you. I would greatly appreciate that. thanks

Comment: You did. I'm sorry that's not what I meant, but I know my English is a mess. I guess what I wanted to say was that those T-shirt looked weird to me.

Comment: general rule when asking a question is to accept the answer that you think is the most helpful, or the answer that was able to answer your question.

Comment: Unfortunately, your answer is unhelpful.  Grammar is not mathematics.  By your rule, when the Rolling Stones sing "I can't get no satisfaction," they really mean that they *can* get satisfaction.  But that's not what the song means.  Double negatives like these are considered nonstandard English, but the extra negation is usually an intensifier.

Comment: ohh, that's what you meant.... I want to vote to your answer, because it was the best answer, but I don't have enough reputation yet to vote.

Comment: If you don't want rules of mathematics, then try "Rules of Negation in logic".

Comment: I just compared the sentence to the application of that rule in mathematics. It does not necessarily means that you would literally use rules on mathematics which obviously applies  only to numbers.

Comment: Mathematics is not just "numbers". Logic is the field of mathematics that deals with propositions in a formal language.  The grammar of natural languages is not logic.  What do you think the Rolling Stones meant?

Comment: Pink Floyd's "We don't need no education. We don't need no thought control" [*First, if you remember the second time they sing through the verse, it's just a bunch of kids singing it; "we don't need no" is absolutely something a school age working class kid with a Cockney accent in England in the 70s might say instead of "we need no" or "we don't need".*](http://musicfans.stackexchange.com/a/2635)